# Average point in a Banach Space

Tags: general-topology, geometry, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we get the average of several vectors $x_1,...,x_n$ by adjusting $\bar{x}$ to minimize the sum of squares:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n d(\bar{x},x_i)^2.
$$
Do we have similar result for general metric space? Is there any articles about it?

Comment: Senseless for general metric space.  But it is a good question for Banach space, as in your title.  Kavi's answer notes that can fail even in a 2-dimensional Banach space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is true in any inner product space. In fact  any finite dimensional subspace of an inner product space can be identified with $\mathbb R^{n}$ for some n, so no new proof is required. In a general  metric space average  of  elements  does  not  make sense and there is no general formula for the  element that minimizes the sum.  Even in   $\mathbb R^{2}$  if you  change  the metric  to say $d((a,b),(x,y))=|x-a|+|y-b|$ the result is not true.